# Unhelpful suggested autocomplete tags when editing HTML & CSS with Aptana Studio

Tags: php, html, eclipse, css

I switched from PHPed to Aptana 3 because of the Zen Coding Addon which is not available for PHPed.

My Problem is as follows:

I'm coding HTML / CSS. When I type `<div st` the first suggestion is for `<style type="text/css" media="screen"></style>` (not good, never need this) and the second is the correct one to autocomplete my style tag.

I heard that this was changed in 3.0.4 - is it possible to define autosuggestions?

Another problem is when I create a `<div>` and after the autocomplete I want to go to the inside of the `<div>` by pressing enter but the curser just jumps behind that complete `<div>`.

Comment: My solution would be "become a faster typist and switch to Vim". I suspect this will be closed as editor-specific support isn't really a "programming" question.

Comment: simply changing of the IDE serves the purpose, changing the entire standard for this is not recommended. it may make code a very unreadable one.

Comment: when i type "<div st" - why should i get the proposal for "<style type="text"...." ? This is idiotic...

Comment: @meager - this is however a question about configuring a programming tool which is on-topic here.

Comment: Can you provide some screenshots to demonstrate this issue?

Comment: @linuxeasy: "changing of the IDE" is left to the developers of the IDE to handle, and is also known as "fixing of bugs". The rest of your comment makes no sense. (Neither does meagar's for the matter.)